# unable to add visual editor to media wiki 1.27.1

Tags: php, mediawiki, visual-editor

I have followed mediawiki site http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor
to set up visual editor.Edited the localsettings.php page as follows 
after the end of the page i had added

`wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );
wfLoadExtension ( 'VisualEditor' );
$wgDefaultUserOptions['VisualEditor-enable'] = 1;
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'VisualEditor-enable';`

opened my browser and created a new wiki page, gone to edit option but could not find visual editor there. Whatever changes i made in localsettings page did not reflect in the edit page.

mediawiki version--1.27.1

VisualEditor-REL1_27

wamp-3.0.4

Thanks